# Using Microsoft PP Functions in vba code?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I wrote a vba macro for PowerPoint. All works well but I miss one step.

So far my macro ends by selecting a certain group of shapes on a slide. After it finishes I go back to PowerPoint and use the "Group" button to make a group out of the selected shapes.

How can I use this Micorsoft Group function in my code. I only manage to group all shapes on a slide to one group or I get an error.

I have tryed:
ActivePresentation.slide(1).shapes.selected.group
but that doesn't work.

I have read this:

[How do I group a set of shapes programmatically in excel 2007 vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245725/how-do-i-group-a-set-of-shapes-programmatically-in-excel-2007-vba)

but several names of shapes are identical, so that doesn't really work. And I do not know how to store the indexnumber of a shape into a variable - which would be a second option to solve my problem.

Basically the Microsoft own functions does exactly what I would need now, right? I takes the shapes that are selected and groups them to a group. can I just call this function within my macro?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got the shapes selected, then this should do it:

Activewindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Group

Comment: Many thanks. That simple code is the solution for now. --> Solved

Comment: Thanks for the edit btw. Just saw that I should use script in stead of macro.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Range(Array(2, 3, 4)).Group
```

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Range(Array("this", "that", "other")).Group
```

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Range(Array("this", 42, 3)).Group
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. But it is not really what I am searching for. See my code below. After the code the selected shapes should be grouped. 
`code`         
For Each Shape In ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNumber).Shapes
            For l = LBound(Group) To UBound(Group)
                If Shape.Id = Group(l) Then
                    If l = 1 Then
                        Shape.Select
                    Else
                        Shape.Select Replace:=False
                    End If
                End If
            Next l
        Next 
`code`

Comment: On the other hand: If I need those index numbers [Array(2, 3, 4) - in your example] how can I access or store them to an array? I understood that they are NOT identical with the Shape.ID and NOT identical with the Zordernumber. Now while iterating through the shapes - as in above comment - can I somehow say: NewArrayXY(l) = Shape.indexnumber? Then I would be able to refer to that. But I haven't found a way to do so.  Many thanks for further help.

Comment: This is what you are searching for because you [don't want to select things](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683) when you work with things. The `ShapeGroup` selects shapes by name or by index. You seem to create shapes and store their `Id`s in the array `Group` - just store the `Name`s instead, then call `ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Range(Group).Group`. Two shapes cannot have identical names, trying to set a duplicated name raises the error number 70.